# C# wpf datagrid with observablecollection. After a user sorts, I can not get the selecctedindex of the observablecollection

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid with an observable collection.

```
 <DataGrid Name="DataGridMemoryTable" AlternatingRowBackground="Beige" Canvas.Left="87" Canvas.Top="30" Width="500" Height="300" RowHeight="20" ColumnWidth="60"
                      SelectionMode="Single" CanUserSortColumns = "False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="10" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                      CurrentCellChanged="DataGridMemoryTableCellChanged" Sorting="DataGridMemoryTable_Sorted"/>
```

And

```
public ObservableCollection<SavedMemorySWL> SavedMemorySWLObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<SavedMemorySWL>();
    public class SavedMemorySWL : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public String Frequency { get; set; }
        public String Time { get; set; }
        public String Days { get; set; }
        public String ITU_Station { get; set; }
        public String Language_Target_Remarks { get; set; }
        public String Program_Start_Stop { get; set; }
        public String ATAUTOinductor { get; set; }
        public String ATAUTOcapacitor { get; set; }
        public String Antenna { get; set; }
        public Boolean Scan { get; set; }
        public String AT200PCinductor { get; set; }
        public String AT200PCcapacitor { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

and after adding rows into the ObservableCollection...

```
Global.MW.DataGridMemoryTable.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                if (Global.MW != null)
                {
                    Global.MW.DataGridMemoryTable.ItemsSource = SavedMemorySWLObservableCollection;
                    Global.MW.DataGridMemoryTable.Items.Refresh();
                    Global.MW.textBoxFileName.Text = memoryRows.FileName;
                }
            }));
```

So, the problem is that if I allow column sorting by the user, then later I get the selected row, and it does not match the row in the ObservableCollection.

```
//int row = DataGridMemoryTable.SelectedIndex;
        int row = DataGridMemoryTable.Items.IndexOf(DataGridMemoryTable.SelectedItem);    //.SelectedIndex;
```

So, after sorting the user clicks a button to do something with his selected row.  If it is the top row, the selectedindex is 0.  But the values in the ObservableCollection are not sorted and I do this operation on the wrong ObservableCollection row.

My current approach is to not permit sorting by the user.

Does somebody have an idea how to convert the selectedindex into an index into the ObservableCollection?

Comment: When the user sorts a column sort the ObservableCollection instead of the data in the DataGrid.

Comment: I'm confused why you're manually updating your data grid. ObservableCollections automatically inform objects that are bound to them when they change. Your DataGrid's Binding expression is simply {Binding}, which means it's using the parent DataContext - is the parent DataContext your ObservableCollection? It should be - if you make it so, the updating should take care of itself, and this problem should go away.

Comment: jdweng.  That is a good idea.  It is extra work/coding, but it is a doable solution.  The "Sorted" event passes DatGridSortingEventArgs e.  e.Column.SortMemberPath and e.Column.SortDirection give information about the user initiated sort.            Travis. Yes, if the user makes changes to the datagrid, the ObservableCollection automatically is changed.  However it appears that a user initiated column sort on the datagrid is not reflected in the ObservableCollection.

Comment: Travis, I read your comment again.  I do not know anything about DataContext.  I actually have two observable collections which I attach to the datagrid by setting ItemSource (only one collection at any given time).   It has been working well with only ItemSource specified. I am not sure what to specify for DataContext, but I will look into it if it solves the user sorting problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did search before asking this question, but after even more searching I found the answer.

[Sort ObservableCollection bound to DataGrid in MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18475883/sort-observablecollection-bound-to-datagrid-in-mvvm)

The answer is that it is not possible.

User Sorting the datagrid never modifies the underlining data in the observablecollection.  There is no way to accomplish this.  Apparently Microsoft did not anticipate anyone would want the underlining data to also get sorted, so there is no property setting or method to accomplish this.

User Sorting only affects the data in an ICollectionView.  However there is a way to look at and copy the ICollectionView as shown in posting number 2 in that thread.

```
    public ICollectionView myCVSWL { get; set; }
internal SavedMemorySWL[] MemoriesSWL = new SavedMemorySWL[MAX_ROWS_SWL];
.
.
.
 Global.MW.DataGridMemoryTable.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                if (Global.MW != null)
                {
                    myCVSWL = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(SavedMemorySWLObservableCollection);
                    Global.MW.DataGridMemoryTable.ItemsSource = myCVSWL;    // SavedMemorySWLObservableCollection;
                    Global.MW.DataGridMemoryTable.Items.Refresh();
                    Global.MW.textBoxFileName.Text = memoryRows.FileName;
                }
            }));
.
.
.





                        int k = 0;
                    foreach (var item in myCVSWL.OfType<SavedMemorySWL>())
                    {
                        memoryRows.MemoriesSWL[k].Frequency = item.Frequency;
                        memoryRows.MemoriesSWL[k].Time = item.Time;
                        memoryRows.MemoriesSWL[k].Days = item.Days;
                        memoryRows.MemoriesSWL[k].ITU_Station = item.ITU_Station;
                        memoryRows.MemoriesSWL[k].Language_Target_Remarks = item.Language_Target_Remarks;
                        memoryRows.MemoriesSWL[k].Program_Start_Stop = item.Program_Start_Stop;
                        memoryRows.MemoriesSWL[k].ATAUTOinductor = item.ATAUTOinductor;
                        memoryRows.MemoriesSWL[k].ATAUTOcapacitor = item.ATAUTOcapacitor;
                        memoryRows.MemoriesSWL[k].Antenna = item.Antenna;
                        memoryRows.MemoriesSWL[k].Scan = item.Scan;
                        memoryRows.MemoriesSWL[k].AT200PCinductor = item.AT200PCinductor;
                        memoryRows.MemoriesSWL[k].AT200PCcapacitor = item.AT200PCcapacitor;
                        k++;
                    }
```

Thank you to those who gave this some thought and tried to help.

Regards,
Howard

Comment: I have backed-out all these changes and disabled datagrid column sorting because the ICollectionView appears to not support the INotifyPropertyChanged.  I find working with tables to be a PITA with both Java/Swing and VS/WPF.